# Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object HTMLInputElement])

Tags: html, reactjs, dom, jsx

I am getting some form elements from an API, API response is given like this:
[image]
I have parsed that string with DOMParser as HTMLElement and I want to add that as React component, the form element is given below:
[image]

on getting this I am setting the form element in a state `formEl`, I added the state in my render function but it is giving the above error, my component is written like this:

```
{gateway.name === "KiplePay" && (
  <div className="col-12 mb-4 mt-4 paymentGatewayBlock">
    <button onClick={this.onClickKiplepay}>Pay with Kiplepay</button>
  </div>
)}
{this.state.formEl}
```

The error says it is still an object, maybe I have to convert it to HTML element, but how do I do that? it is showing already an HTML element in console.

Comment: Can you provide (update your question please) the entire API response object, not just the HTML portion, and all the response processing logic, so that we may see what it looks like when fetched, and everything done to it up to when you attempt to render it?

Comment: @DrewReese Yeah please check the response I added in the description

Comment: @suvodipMondal, can you please try this library react-html-parser, this will detect your HTML code from API.

Comment: @Riddhi thanks, I just used `document.body.append(formEl)` to add the form element